# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am busy with a stored procedure to calculate production numbers of shifts. I already have an idea on how to do that but for some kind of strange reason I do not get an insert into with a variable time working. Below is query for the stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProductionReport] 
     @filterStartTime datetime,
     @filterEndTime datetime,
     @machine varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE #tempProductionTable(
id varchar(3),
ploeg varchar(3),
starttime2 datetime,
endtime2 datetime,
daynumber int)

declare @i int
, @SQLString  varchar(400)
, @id varchar(3)
, @ploeg varchar(3)
, @starttime datetime
, @endtime datetime

set @i = 0

while @i < 16
begin
set @i = @i+1
set @id = @i
set @starttime = convert(datetime, @filterStartTime,110)
print @starttime
set @ploeg = '2'
SET @SQLString = 'INSERT INTO #tempProductionTable (id,ploeg,starttime2) values ('+@id+','+@ploeg+','+@starttime+')'
EXEC(@SQLString)
end

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT * from #tempProductionTable
END
```

And this is the query for opening the stored procedure:

```
USE [NRPConfiguration]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC @return_value = [dbo].[ProductionReport]
@filterStartTime = '2017-01-01 10:00:00.000',
@filterEndTime = N'2-1-2017 0:00',
@machine = N'ASM_008'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

I already tried a lot of things but still can't get it working. For example when I manually insert a time than it is working. But when I want to do it with an variable it is not working also when I am using the convert function for it. What am I doing wrong?

I use SQL Server 2008 R2 for this.

Comment: When I hard code a datetime, I use `{ts 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'}` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quit concatenating strings to executed dynamic sql, use [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) instead.

Your error can be correct by specifying dates in ISO format (or in the format Dan Bracuk mentioned in his comment). e.g. `'2017-04-01T23:59:59.363'`

[#BackToBasics : Dating Responsibly - Aaron Bertrand](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-dating-responsibly/)

---

Here is how you would use `sp_executesql` instead:

```
alter procedure [dbo].[ProductionReport] (
     @filterStartTime datetime,
     @filterEndTime datetime,
     @machine varchar(10)
  ) as
begin;
-- set nocount on added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with select statements.
set nocount on;
create table #tempProductionTable(
    id varchar(3)
  , ploeg varchar(3)
  , starttime2 datetime
  , endtime2 datetime
  , daynumber int
  );

declare @i int
  , @params nvarchar(max)
  , @sqlstring nvarchar(max)
  , @id varchar(3)
  , @ploeg varchar(3)
  , @starttime datetime
  , @endtime datetime;

set @params = '@id int, @ploeg varchar(3), @starttime datetime';
set @sqlstring = 'insert into #tempProductionTable (id,ploeg,starttime2) values (@id,@ploeg,@starttime);';

set @i = 0

while @i < 16
begin
  set @i = @i+1
  set @id = @i
  set @starttime = convert(datetime, @filterStartTime,110)
  set @ploeg = '2'
  print @starttime
  exec sp_executesql @sqlstring, @params, @id, @ploeg, @starttime;
end

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
select * from #tempProductionTable
end;
go
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/KPBR1056

Comment: I also tried the ISO format without success. When I change filterStartTime = '2017-01-01 10:00:00.000', to this: filterStartTime = '2017-04-01T23:59:59.363', then I still have the same error.

Comment: @renebiemans Quit concatenating strings to executed dynamic sql, use [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) instead.

Comment: This indeed works. Thank you for your respone. This is the soluation :D